# androidannotations2.7.1 - AndroidManifest.xml file contains the original component

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am having trouble configuring [androidannotation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations), just downloaded androidannotations-bundle-2.7.1.zip.

I have a LoginActivity that makes use of @EActivity annotation and after building I am getting  below error:

```
The AndroidManifest.xml file contains the original component, and not the AndroidAnnotations generated component. Please register LoginActivity_ instead of LoginActivity
```

Eclipse: 3.7.2
I've attached some images that may be relevant. Please let me know if you need anything else.

[image: Annotation Processing-1]
[image: Annotation Processing-2]
[image: Java-Build-Path]
[image: Java-6-enabled]

So is there anything wrong with this release (really doubting), or it's just something wrong with my configuration (most probably)?

Thanks!

P.S. I am aware of this [similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/androidannotations/issues/detail?id=89), but I believe I put the jars right.!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the yoyo that created this thread (me!) doesn't know how to use AndroidAnnotations. If he would have spent more effort in researching how it works, he would have found [this article](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/HowItWorks).

So the solution is straight-forward and is described in the error, simply add the "_" in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity_"
```

Comment: Yea, but how If Android Studio do not generate them ?